# How to get a data field from a Firebase Firestore document using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This function is in Cloud Functions, I would like to know how I can get only one field of a specific document, and not just fetch all document data. My Code:

```
export const onNewOrder = functions.firestore.document("/orders/{orderId}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  const orderId = context.params.orderId;

  // Where do I specify the data from which field I want to fetch?
  const snap = await admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc(orderId).get();
  console.log(snap.data());
});
```

Where do I specify the data from which field I want to fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore client-side SDKs always retrieve the entire document. There is no way to specify that only certain fields should be retrieved from the server.

This option *does* exist in the server-side/Admin SDKs, such as the one for Node.js.

For more on this, see [How to access a specific field from Cloud FireStore Firebase in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312485/how-to-access-a-specific-field-from-cloud-firestore-firebase-in-swift), [Firestore get document except some fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920465/firestore-get-document-except-some-fields)

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the DocumentSnapshot that is returned and select which Map field I want set in a variable? On Dart it would be something like:

Comment: `final DocumentSnapshot docUser = await firestore.collection('users').document(currentUser.uid).get();
name = docUser.data['name'] as String;`

Comment: How do I do the same in TS?

Comment: You mean  something like `console.log(snap.data()["name"])`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to write like this, but it's not accepted, and it shows the error "Possibly the object is null"

Comment: So did you then add a null check (`if snap.data() != null)`), or hard-cast to non-null (`snap.data()!.name`)?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I figured out how to access a value from a map. Simply put: `snap.get("value")`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there any particular reason _why_ it's not possible to specify only certain fields be returned?  While I understand such functionality may facilitate bad behaviors if used for faux-security measures, there are legitimate use cases where reducing a payload size delivered to a client would be very helpful.

Comment: It would thoroughly complicate the client-side caching, since we'd no longer be able to assume two snapshots of the same document would be equivalent.